# What is significance of comma (,) in .x file

Tags: directx, directx-9

I am loading and writing DirectX .x file. I am trying to follow a third party application in the way it loads the file. 
If I have following mesh:

Mesh obj1 {

```
4;

6.500000;-3.656250;0.000000;,
-6.500000;3.656250;0.000000;,
-6.500000;-3.656250;0.000000;,
6.500000;3.656250;0.000000;;
```

In this, even if I remove the commas and write everything in one line, the third party tool is still able to load the file.

I couldn't find a proper documentation that describes role of comma. It is quite possible that only this tool is loading it this way. Can you please inform me about the role of comma in .x file (particularly in Mesh).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commas are used to separate array members. For brief description follow the link http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/directx/#xfilefrm_Use_of_commas